# Clicking noise problem

Tags: noise, clicking

I started having clicking noises when I pedal hard. I tried to isolate the problem, and that's what I found.

The clicking happens when I push on the pedal as shown in this video:

And it also happens when I pull in the other direction (up):

(In this case, I can pull on the crank instead of a pedal and the sound is the same)

I'm pretty new to bicycles, so I'm unsure about the problem here. It appears to me that the sound happens when I alternate between pushing and pulling (or pushing on the other pedal). I tried tightening the bottom bracket and the cranks, and I think they are tightened properly, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Is you pedal tightened in the crank? How old is the bike?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I think the pedal is tightened. But I can replicate that sound without even touching it as I mentioned in the post, so it shouldn't be a problem? And the bike is a few months old, so fairly new.

Comment: Given the age of the bike i'd take it to the local bike shop. It might still be repaired under warranty.